# python3; ctypes; pointer to array

Tags: python, pointers, dll, ctypes

I want to call a function (AES_crypt) by the module of ctypes, the function comes from xx.dll, this is my code (python 3.6.1):

```
def fillprototype(f, restype, argtypes):
f.restype  = restype
f.argtypes = argtypes

def tuple2pointer(number):
    size     = len(number)
    c_number = (c_ulong * size)(*number)
    cnum     = cast(c_number, POINTER(c_ulong))
    return cnum

type_array_ulong = POINTER(c_ulong)

fillprototype(AES_crypt,        c_ulong, [type_array_ulong, 
type_array_ulong, c_ulong, type_array_ulong, type_array_ulong, 
type_array_ulong, c_ulong, c_ulong] )

iv  = tuple2pointer(iv)
pa  = tuple2pointer(pa)
pt  = tuple2pointer(pt)
ct  = tuple2pointer(ct)
rt  = tuple2pointer(rt)
key = tuple2pointer(key)

AES_crypt(
        byref(rt),
        byref(ct), 
        blk_len, 
        byref(iv), 
        byref(key),
        byref(pa),
        AES_DECRYPT,
        AES_ECB_MODE
        )
```

the prototype of C function is:

```
AES_crypt(
               UINT32 *dataout,
               UINT32 *datain, 
               UINT32 block_len, 
               UINT32 *iv, 
               UINT32 *ks,
               UINT32 *para,
               UINT32 enc_dec_sel,
               UINT32 ecb_cbc_sel
              );
```

BUT , the debug information is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Project\python\aes_vs\aes_vs\aes_vs.py", line 113, in 
<module>
AES_ECB_MODE
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_ulong 
instance instead of pointer to LP_c_ulong
```

I want to why and what i can do?
thank you!

Comment: Arrays are passed as a pointer to the first element. Your function should be `tuple2array`, with no `cast` to a pointer. When passing an array (not a pointer), `byref` won't cause a problem, but it's actually redundant. Just pass the array.

Comment: Thanks.  I comment outcode:
     cnum     = cast(c_number, POINTER(c_ulong))
but, my debugger terminated unexpectedly
I was stunned

Comment: If you commented out the line that defines `cnum`, then what is your function returning? It should return the `c_number` array.

Comment: yes, you are right, the value of return is `c_number` instead of `c_num`, but, my debugger terminated unexpectedly I was stunned.I wonder if there are any other alternatives?